# When export as Qgistoweb . The line is not adjusting automatically

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

As you can see in the Image , Normally project is showing the line above sea level 1430 ft .

When i expor
[image]

Comment: Is the "Match Project CRS" option selected in the Appearance tab? In addition to the preview, have you tried performing an export, both with openlayers and with leaflet?

Comment: Soon there will be an update to qgis2web dedicated to perfectly showing dotted or dotted lines

Comment: I fixed the issue , We have to convert the raster layer to vector layer to solve this issue .

Comment: This is unusual. Normally this shouldn't happen with xyz layers or rasters.